# Do not receive Microsoft graph change notifications when user manage user roles

Tags: push-notification, microsoft-graph-api

We're using Microsoft Graph API to receive user change notifications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

It works fine when managing all user's data except when managing user roles.
In that case we are not receiving notifications.

Is this a known issue or ... ?

Regards,

Pavle Kukric

Comment: There are 2 ways a user can be assigned to a role
1.Make a role assignment from within PIM UI blade or via PIM API or via PIM Powershell module 2.Make a role assignment from the IAM blade without visiting any PIM blades/API

Comment: In the first case (within PIM assignment), PIM has the capability to read role settings and trigger email notifications to Admins including other emails configured in the role settings. The whole workflow happens within the PIM ecosystem. 
In the second case (Outside PIM assignment), PIM worker role polls for AAD to read the role assignments periodically and triggers a special email notification to Admins. In this case, the recipients can only be Admin user profile - email ids.

Comment: Are you still looking any help on this question